# Can't vote from my phone

Tags: bug, mobile-web

It's been a while, but I've had enough of it.

I am using Firefox on Nexus 4, and it seems that I can't vote from my phone when browsing in "full site" mode. The mobile site allows voting, the SE application allows voting. But the full site doesn't.

All the other functions work fine (flagging, voting to close, even requesting the +/- vote count).

(I tried clearing the cache, several times, and it didn't work.)

Comment: I can attest that voting on the full site works in Chrome (on my Nexus 4), so it's probably an issue with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks, Najib. I wonder how many people wanted to vote on this, but couldn't. :-P

Comment: Have repro on Android Firefox 41.0. Interestingly, clicking on the number between the up/down vote buttons does correctly reveal the counts (oh wait, you already said this in the question).

Comment: @Chris: That's good to hear. Maybe you have a better idea as to how to debug this sort of problem (I have no idea).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Further update testing: I've managed to make the vote buttons do something, but it requires hitting the button at a very specific location. Probably some kind of stylesheet issue. I'll get back to you when I figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AsafKaragila this is unrelated, but I find firefox to be worst browser on android.(best one on pc though). Just don't use it.

Comment: I'm ***really*** surprised by the close vote. What's unclear? Moreover a core developer reproduced the bug. Is there any discussion left?

Comment: @G-man: That may be, I have an aversion to Chrome and its variants.

Comment: Well, there's always Opera...

Comment: @Chris: Any news?